# How to use List<String> params in Restrictions.like

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, criteria, dropwizard

I use `List` objects in `Restrictions.in` methods, now I must use this case at `Restrictions.like`
But `Restrictions.like` doesn't receive `List` param. How Can I solve this problem?
My code is bottom:

```java
public void setPhones(Set<String> phones) {
    this.phones.addAll(phones);
    if (!this.phones.isEmpty()) {
        aliases.add(new QueryAlias("profile", "profile"));
        criterions.add(Restrictions.like("profile.phone", this.phones));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Correcting my prior (and now edited) answer**

According to documentation (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html) it seems you don't have a direct way to do this.

You can try iterating your List, then create a List of [Restriction.like](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#like-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) for each of your phones then converting this list into an array to use into a [Restrictions.or](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#or-org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion...-):

```
public void setPhones(Set<String> phones) {

    this.phones.addAll(phones);

    if (!this.phones.isEmpty()) {
        // Creates a list to store criterions
        List<Criterion> criterionsPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

        // For each number searched, it creates a criterion with a "Like Restriction" adding to criterionsPhoneNumbers List. 
        // Pay attention to match mode (in raw sql it'll be a "like" using %phoneNumber% - check the generated SQL by hibernate).
        // You can change this to suit your needs.
        for (String number : numbers) {
            aliases.add(new QueryAlias("profile", "profile"));
            criterionsPhoneNumbers.add( Restrictions.like("number", number, MatchMode.ANYWHERE)  ) ;
        }

        // Here criterionsPhoneNumbers is being converted to array then added to the criteria with "Or Restriction" 
        criteria.add(Restrictions.or( criterionsPhoneNumbers.toArray(new Criterion[restrictionsPhoneNumbers.size()]) ));
    }


}
```

My prior answer was wrong because adding each phone number as a Restriction.like (only) wasn't enough and was converted to a sql with a logical 'and' in 'where' clause. As I hadn't tested then I couldn't see the error.
I had implemented then I saw the error.
My apologies.

Comment: Could you post the error/exception which has been thrown?

Comment: Jorge Duarte, not any error but not also expected result

Comment: I've implemented and now it works. My example's implementation is available at [github](https://github.com/jorgefcduarte/hibernate-examples/tree/master/phones)

Comment: Hi, @ShavkatTurakulov. As the answer has helped and worked for you, could you accept it?

Comment: @JorgeDuarteI.  didnt test it yet, but I trusted that it should work. When I tested, there aren't this line:    `criteria.add(Restrictions.or( criterionsPhoneNumbers.toArray(new Criterion[restrictionsPhoneNumbers.size()]) )); `